# How can I remove a specific PNR from a Queue in Sabre SOAP API

Tags: soap, sabre

I use GetReservationRQ to retrieve a named PNR. I would then like to remove this PNR from the queue. I have tried to use QueueAccessRQ

QueueAccessRQ with `<Navigation Action=""QR""/>`
returns "CANNOT DO THIS IF OFF QUEUE"

QueueAccessRQ with `<Navigation Action=""E""/>`
returns "NO CHANGES MADE TO PNR - UPDATE OR IGNORE"

QueueAccessRQ with `<Navigation Action=""QR""/><Selection Function=""PR"" Criteria=""ABC123""/>`
returns "Navigation, Selection are mutually exclusive"

Even if I do IgnoreTransactionRQ or EndTransactionRQ before QueueAccessRQ, the messages are the same, except 
IgnoreTransactionRQ followed by QueueAccessRQ with `<Navigation Action=""E""/>`
returns "UNABLE TO END TRANSACTION - NO PNR PRESENT IN WORK AREA"

How can I remove a specific PNR from a Queue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This means you are not working on Queue Mode - QR will not work if not in Queue Mode

QueueAccessRQ with  returns "CANNOT DO THIS IF OFF QUEUE"

Comment: I am a bit more knowledgeable about how the process works now.   

I was processing on-queue and my moves were failing.   

I was processing off-queue and my removes were failing.    


The error comes about because I can remove(QR) or ignore(I) while on-queue, but to move(QueueMoveRQ) a pnr I must be off-queue.  
  


I am trying to read a queue and remove, ignore or move each PNR.  
The solution was to process on-queue and go off queue for Moves, while storing a position in the queue.  

After the Move, I must go back on-queue and navigate to previous position.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use QueueAccessLLSRQ along with GetReservationRQ but you do have to use a stateful request (and session tokens).

You'd want to do something like:

1. SessionCreateRQ
2. GetReservationRQ
3. QueueAccessLSSRQ
4. SessionCloseRQ

Your GetReservation could look something like:

```
<GetReservationRQ xmlns="http://webservices.sabre.com/pnrbuilder/v1_18" Version="1.18.0">
    <Locator>****RECORD LOCATOR HERE****</Locator>
    <RequestType>Stateful</RequestType>
    <ReturnOptions>
        <SubjectAreas>
            <SubjectArea>HEADER</SubjectArea>
        </SubjectAreas>
        <ViewName>Simple</ViewName>
        <ResponseFormat>STL</ResponseFormat>
    </ReturnOptions>
</GetReservationRQ>
```

Then QueueAccessLLSRQ:

```
<QueueAccessRQ xmlns="http://webservices.sabre.com/sabreXML/2011/10" ReturnHostCommand="true" Version="2.0.6">
  <Navigation Action="QR" />
  <QueueIdentifier PseudoCityCode="****PCC HERE****" Number="****QUEUE NUMBER HERE****" />
</QueueAccessRQ>
```

Also keep in mind that any other changes made to the PNR between the GetReservationRQ and QueueLLSRQ calls would be end-transacted when removing from queue.

Comment: Dear Jmason, I had problem same Don. I saw your workflow incorrect. By techspecs sabre api then you need to read queue before getreservation.

Comment: @DavidLeep This workflow does work, I use this workflow routinely. There are 2 ways to use the queue commands, either in queue mode or in PNR mode. If you are in queue mode then the QR action cannot take a queue number, it will remove the PNR from the currently active queue. When working in PNR mode, i.e. QueueAccessLLSRQ is not called to load, then QR needs to know what queue to remove.